# Three 12 column grid side by side using twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was creating a personal website using bootstrap and I wanted to create this specific layout :

[image]

Each part is 940 px wide with 12 columns so when the screen views 1 of the 3 parts the other 2 are hidden how can i execute this?

Thanks alot for all your help!

Comment: Do you intend to use JS to change your *view* ? If so, have you though about using the default grid, and just hide or show the one you want ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the default 12-column bootstrap grid, with this markup :

```
<div class="container supercontainer">
    <div class="supercontainer-inner clearfix view-1">
        <div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="span12"><p>Grid 1</p></div></div></div>
        <div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="span12"><p>Grid 2</p></div></div></div>
        <div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="span12"><p>Grid 3</p></div></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this CSS :

```css
.supercontainer {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.supercontainer-inner {
    width: 2820px;
  -webkit-transition: margin-left 0.35s ease;
     -moz-transition: margin-left 0.35s ease;
       -o-transition: margin-left 0.35s ease;
          transition: margin-left 0.35s ease;
}
.supercontainer-inner > .container {
    float: left!important;
}


.supercontainer-inner.view-1 { margin-left: 0; }
.supercontainer-inner.view-2 { margin-left: -940px; }
.supercontainer-inner.view-3 { margin-left: -1880px; }
```

Keep in mind that better effects can be achieved by using the carousel stylesheet.

Check the [demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/8CQtU/2/embedded/result/) the see one possible application to switch *views*.

---

And this is a **responsive** version of it [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/8CQtU/3/embedded/result/).

But this would need some cleaning up into a LESS script, with a variable for the number of views (and maybe just extend the basic grid.. hum).

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .supercontainer-inner.view-1 { margin-left: 0; }
    .supercontainer-inner.view-2 { margin-left: -1170px; }
    .supercontainer-inner.view-3 { margin-left: -2340px; }
    .supercontainer-inner {
        width: 3510px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 979px) {
    .supercontainer-inner.view-1 { margin-left: 0; }
    .supercontainer-inner.view-2 { margin-left: -724px; }
    .supercontainer-inner.view-3 { margin-left: -1448px; }
    .supercontainer-inner {
        width: 2172px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .supercontainer-inner.view-1 { margin-left: 0; }
    .supercontainer-inner.view-2 { margin-left: -100%; }
    .supercontainer-inner.view-3 { margin-left: -200%; }
    .supercontainer-inner {
        width: 300%;
    }
    .supercontainer-inner >.container { width: 33.33%!important; }
}
```